# reach parent method using Objects type inheritance

Tags: oracle, object, inheritance, plsql

I have Object B child of Object A. In object B I would like to call a method from Object A.

It looks like in Oracle 11 we can use this :

```
(SELF AS parent_object).parent_method
```

But I work with Oracle 10 and this does not work. Is there another way ?

Thank you

PS : I want to do that in the CONSTRUCTOR METHOD (maybe it changes something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this feature was introduced in 11.1, as mentioned in [What's New in Object-Relational Features?](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/whatsnew.htm).

The [10g manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjbas.htm#sthref300) also talks about this limitation.  The best available workaround is to create a static supertype method:

> When implementing methods using PL/SQL, you cannot call a supertype
>   object method with the super keyword or an equivalent method in
>   derived objects that have overriding methods. However, you can call a
>   static supertype method as a workaround. See the examples in "Creating
>   Subtypes With Overriding Methods" for the definition of the supertype
>   and subtype functions.

Answer (score 0):

With **extreme** care (it means, that whatever you will do to prevent problems, in future you anyway will get a lot of pain in different parts of your body) you can cast child type to parent type and call its methods.

Extreme care is needed because, of course, you will lose any changes made on member fields by call to this method. So you can use such way only with base methods that does not change member fields of type.

```
create type type_1 as object (
    field1 number(1)
    ,member procedure init
) not final;
/

create or replace type body type_1 as

member procedure init as
begin
    field1 := 0;
    dbms_output.put_line('init works! Field1 = ' || field1);
end;

end;
/


create type type_2
under type_1 (
    field2 number(1)
    ,constructor function type_2(self in out type_2, arg number) return self as result
);
/

create or replace type body type_2 as

constructor function type_2(self in out type_2, arg number) return self as result as
    parent    type_1;
begin
    self.field2 := arg;
    self.field1 := -1;

    select self
    into parent
    from dual;

    parent.init();

    dbms_output.put_line('Child''s field1 = ' || self.field1);
    return;
end;

end;
/


declare
    child    type_2 := type_2(2);
begin
    return;
end;
/
```